# Convexity of $\log \det(I+(P-\text{tr}(X))\cdot X)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, optimization, convex-analysis

where $P-\text{tr}(X)>0$ and $X$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements are $(x_1,x_2,\dots x_m)$

Comment: is it $log det (I+(P-tr(X))*X)$? If $X$ is a matrix then $(P-tr(X))>0$ is a scalar. It can't be a matrix. Is your bracket are misplaced?

Comment: thanks for your help! Yes,P-tr(x) is a scalar,we can name it by 't', then p-tr(x)*x means t.*(X), diagonal elements now are (tx1,tx2,...txm) so it still a matirx

Answer (score 1):

If $f(X)=\log\det(X) $, then $f(X)$ is a **concave** function.

If $f$ is convex iff $\forall x \in \operatorname{dom}\ F$, $\forall v$, the function $g(t) = f(x+tv)$ is convex. It check whether a function is convex by restricting it to a line.

Proof:
$g(t) =\log\det (Z+tV)$
$=\log \det(Z^{1/2}(I+tZ^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2})Z^{1/2})$
$=\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1+t\lambda_i) +\log\det Z$

where $\lambda_i$ are eigen values of $Z^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2}$. Therefore we have

$$g'(t)  = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\lambda_i}{1+t\lambda_i}, \text{ and } g''(t)=-\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\lambda_i^2}{(1+t\lambda_i)^2}$$
since $g''(t)<0$, we conclude that $f$ is concave function.

Just apply the above technique to your case.

Comment: Yes I know this method ,but it cannot help~~

Comment: Learner, your post, as you write it, is a non-sense: 1. clearly, you assume that $Z\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, but this domain is not convex. 2. You assume that $Z^{1/2}$ is a real matrix. 3. You assume that the eigenvalues of $Z^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2}$ are real. // In fact, the convexity is true if you consider (for instance) the set of symmetric definite positive matrices.

Answer (score 0):

It's not convex in general. Consider the $2\times2$ case with $P>0$. If the function in question is convex, it is convex in particular on the convex hull of $X=\operatorname{diag}(a,P-k-a)$ and $Y=\operatorname{diag}(P-k-a,a)$, where $a$ and $k$ are arbitrary numbers such that $0\le a\le P-k\le P$. Hence you are essentially suggesting that $g(x)=\log(1+kx)$ is convex on $[0,P]$. Yet $g$ is strictly concave and hence non-convex.